# How to call tabula-java from another program written in php?

Tags: php, pdf, tabular, tabula

## Situation

I have a website written in PHP.

In PHP, I can extract the text inside a pdf file uploaded to the same website and so on.

I found the [tabula-java](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-java) github repo.

## So what's the issue?

I have tried the mac app for tabula. I noticed that I needed to highlight a certain section of the pdf before the table data can be converted.

However, that's not what I want to accomplish. I want to run tabula in the background and on demand. When my website receives a file upload and certain conditions are satisfied, I want to call the tabula as a service somehow and feed it the unstructured data and then get back the tabulated data.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to wrap the [tabula-extractor](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-extractor) command line command and return the results into your application.

For example, in R, the [tabulizer](https://github.com/leeper/tabulizer) package works this way.